# Django form field different clean logic based on UpdateView or CreateView

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-class-based-views

I have a form in Django that is used in both a CreateView and an UpdateView.  One of the field is hours_allocated which cannot be < 0.  In my model, I have declared it as:

```
hours_allocated= models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, validators=[MinValueValidator(Decimal('0.0')), MaxValueValidator(Decimal('24.00'))])
```

When the record is updated (UpdateView) this is fine.  However, in the CreateView, I would like to ensure that the value is > 0 (not = 0.0 as allowed in UpdateView).  If I add a clean_hours_allocated() method to check if the value is > 0, it applies to both the CreateView and UpdateView.

Is there a way to have different validation at the form level based on whether the form is used in an UpdateView or CreateView?  Or, is there a way to properly handle validation in the view itself?

Comment: Can you show your forms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not an expert on Django. However, I think you could do something like this in `forms.py`.

```
def clean_hours_allocated(self):
    if not self.instance.pk: # Update instances have a pk and wouldn't go in this.
        ## Logic to validate Create Instances

    return hours_allocated
```

I don't think this is the perfect solution, but I believe this should fulfill your task.

Answer (score 0):

I believe one approach would be adding a hidden field to your form called something like `mode` which must be one of `{'create', 'update'}`. Then you set the value of this field appropriately based on the view which instantiates the form.

Once this is in place, you could check `cleaned_data['mode']` in your desired validation method (see Django's [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/validation/) for a detailed explanation of the options). Depending on its value, an if-else branch would allow you to apply validation logic differently